# Tracking speed and direction of golf ball

Tags: sensors, direction-finding

I'm working on a prototype for a cheap launch monitor as a cheap alternative to the expensive ones on the market atm.

**Question:**

I'm looking for a sensor or sensors that can track the following

- High-speed objects ~250mph
- Small objects (golf ball)
- Direction left, right, and up
- Preferably a relatively cheap solution (100-200usd)

Which type should I use for that project?

**This is what I have found until now:**

I have found the [OmniPreSense](https://omnipresense.com/) but I'm also looking for alternatives and there is a drawback it seems to not be able to track speeds in excess of 138mph.

Would also be amazing to get feedback from someone that has tried a similar project that I can spare with.

Comment: what is your specific, answerable question?

Comment: The sensors you linked to can handle much higher speeds (over 300 mph) but have limited range (tens of meters), and I doubt they would be able to track something as small as a golf ball, even less at higher distances. Tracking a golf ball is a hard problem, I doubt you’ll find a cheap and effective solution, but you’ll first need to narrow down the type of sensor you want to achieve this.

Comment: I figured out i need a 3D doppler radar sensor i dont need full ball flight if i have direction and speed the rest can be calculated

Comment: @jsotola I updated the question :)

Comment: @SimonDragsbæk something went wrong ... the question shows no edits

Comment: Might have been cached since @jsotola it's actively showing here

Comment: Your question update is not showing. Also note that from direction and speed you can estimate the rest, but not get a precise result, as it won't take into account things like wind and spin.